# Convert string to date and merge data sets R

Tags: r, date, time

I have a column of data in the form of a string, and I need to change it to date because it is a time series.

```
200612010018 --> 2006-12-01 00:18
```

I've tried unsucessfully,

```
strptime(200612010018,format ='%Y%M%D %H:%MM')
```

After doing this I need to append one data set to another one.
Will I have any problems using rbind() if the column contains dates?

Thanks

Comment: If there's no space in the input, then no space on the format. Also no trailing "M"

Answer (score 2):

You were close. You mixed minutes(`%M`) and months (`%m`). And the the `format` argument needs to follow the format you provide.

```
strptime(200612010018,format ='%Y%m%d%H%M')
#"2006-12-01 00:18:00
```